# Как подсчитать количество по каждому месяцу одним запросом, если известен начало и конец работы?

Tags: sql, oracle

Мне необходимо узнать количество сотрудников, которые работали в заданные месяцы, если известна дата начала работы и дата окончания работы.

Моя таблица выглядит так:

| ID | Name | Start_Date | End_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 15.01.2020 | 06.08.2020 |
| 2 | Nikhil | 14.03.2020 | 25.11.2020 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

Ожидаю получить такой результат:

| month | count(ID) |
| --- | --- |
| Jun | 2 |
| Feb | 8 |
| ... | ... |
| Dec | 3 |

Я знаю, как узнать количество для каждого месяца отдельним запросом:

```
Select COUNT(ID)
FROM tab
where Start_Date=<31.01.2020 AND End_date>=01.01.2020
```

Но поскольку такую операцию мне нужду сделать для каждого месяца для нескольких лет, то менять даты вручную для каждого месяца слишком долго.

Comment: CTE, генерирующий список месяцев диапазона.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо просто генерировать табличные значения для каждого месяца в заданном диапазоне времени, а затем соединить их с исходной таблицей. В таблице `params` заданный диапазон - с какого месяца считать, сколько месяцев.

На [db<>fiddle с тестовыми данными](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e062fb61ebc15a8ce02b6d7d787fad25):

```
with params as (
    select date'2020-01-01' from#, 12 months# from dual
)
select to_char (mon, 'Mon rr') month, count (id) 
from (
    select add_months (trunc (from#, 'mm'), level-1) mon 
    from params connect by level<=months#)
left join tab t on (t.sdt <= last_day (mon) and t.edt >= mon)   
group by mon
order by mon
/
```

Результат:

```
MONTH            COUNT(ID)
--------------- ----------
Jan 20                   1
Feb 20                   1
Mar 20                   2
Apr 20                   2
May 20                   2
Jun 20                   2
Jul 20                   2
Aug 20                   3
Sep 20                   2
Oct 20                   2
Nov 20                   1
Dec 20                   0
```